# mvc4 configure session timeout like the websecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-timeout

I have a problem which is the session time out is not the time out for `web security` class,

kindly help me to make are the same

Comment: Did you try setting the  <authentication><forms timeout to the session timeout?

Comment: @Raj i didn't try that cos i dont know what is that. pease tell me in an answer, how to do it and i will accept your answer

Comment: I cannot provide an answer without bit more detail. I suspected the forms timeout, because I assumed you get redirected to the login page. Before I go into more detail, can you please tell me the outcome of being "the session time out is not the timeout for web security". Do you get redirected to a logging page? Do you get a session time out message? Or any other exception?